# Typelite doesn't contain methods in the generated TypeScript file

Tags: .net, typelite

I am trying to explore TypeLite framework to be able to write code in C# and subsequently generate a javascript file(since we need the same code at both client and server side).

I had initial success when I can get all the classes converted to interfaces. However, I am stuck at converting methods. Does TypeLite support converting methods to Typescript as well? TypeLite supports POCO objects, hence, ideally I should be able to generate a Typescript method out of those methods.

Here is the sample code I am trying to run and the output I get:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, string> dict { get; set; }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return Name + Addresses.ToString();
    }
}

public class Concrete
{
    public Person person { get; set; }
    public string name;

    public Concrete()
    {
        person = new Person();
        name = person.GetName();
    }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
}
```

And this is what I get:

```
declare module MvcApplication4.Controllers {
    interface Person {
        Name: string;
        Addresses: MvcApplication4.Controllers.Address[];
        dict: System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<number, string>[];
    }
    interface Address {
        Street: string;
    }
    interface Concrete {
        person: MvcApplication4.Controllers.Person;
    }
    interface Employee extends MvcApplication4.Controllers.Person {
        Salary: number;
    }
}    
declare module System.Collections.Generic {
    interface KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> {
        Key: TKey;
        Value: TValue;
     }
}
```

Notice: I dont get the GetName function in the generated ts file :(
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The TypeLITE doesn't support methods, sorry. The primary goal of the TypeLITE library is to help you maintain type consistency across .NET / TypeScript boundary and not to translate code 1:1 from C# to TypeScript.

E.g. you have a class in C#, you serialize it and send it as JSON to the client and deserialize it. If you add a new property in C# you will get compiler warning if you don't add it in TypeScript as well.

Comment: Thanks Lukas. So I would need to search for some other framework which can convert a C# method to its corresponding typescript/javascript equivalent :(

Comment: You might be interested in the http://scriptsharp.com - it compiles C# code into JavaScript